# How to list ONLY days in a month adding and deleting specific data?

Tags: php

I need to generate a list with every day they are: Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesdays of a given month, however, add a list SOME SATURDAYS to use and exclude some other dates (even if they are Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesdays). THE NUMBERS NEED TO APPEAR IN CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER.

The variables to be used include:

```
$year = 2020; // year to be considered

$mes = 7; // month to be considered

$days_of_week = array ("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"); // days to be considered

$dias_serao_excluidos = array ("07/06/2020", "03/12/2020", "07/13/2020", "07/23/2020", "07/06/2018"); // will only be used 06/07/2020, 07/13/2020 - DATE FORMAT DAY / MONTH / YEAR

$dias_serao_adicionados = array ("7/1/2020", "7/2/2020", "6/3/2020", "4/23/2020", "5/6/2018"); // will only be used 7/1/2020, 7/2/2020 - DATE FORMAT DAY / MONTH / YEAR
```

The expected output would look something like this:

**DAYS OF THE MONTH OF JULY** 
01, 02, 07, 08, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 29

NOTE: I have already researched the forum extensively. None of the questions consider this specificity of the days to be added and to be deleted.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: Is there a certain pattern you're following? And you're saying you want M/T/W, and 'some' saturdays (not clarifying which or why), and exclude some M/T/W (also no reasoning onto it). Perhaps we could come up with a neater algorithm for it that can be used for other months automatically. Otherwise, only solution would be to mention manually the days you want, without the need of $days_of_week nor the other two array values, simply a $days = array ("01", "02", etc..)

Comment: Can you show/explain what you have tried so far so that we can provide more direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have following variables:

```
$excludedDates = ["07/06/2020", "03/12/2020", "07/13/2020", "07/23/2020", "07/06/2018"];
$includedDates = ["7/1/2020", "7/2/2020", "6/3/2020", "4/23/2020", "5/6/2018"];
$whiteDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"];

$year = 2020;
$month = 7;
```

First lets create [DatePeriod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) with all days in selected month:

```
$from = new DateTimeImmutable("$year-$month");
$to = $from->modify('last day of this month');
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($from, DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'), $to);
```

then convert iterator to array:

```
$dates = iterator_to_array($datePeriod);
```

now you can filter the array with values you need:

```
$filtered = array_filter($dates, function (DateTimeImmutable $day) use ($includedDates, $excludedDates, $whiteDays) {
    if (in_array($day->format('n/j/Y'), $includedDates)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (in_array($day->format('m/d/Y'), $excludedDates)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (in_array($day->format('l'), $whiteDays)) {
        return true;
    }
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect, it works very well.

How could I let the day show?
The array looks like this: [0]=> 
object(DateTimeImmutable)#5 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-07-01 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(17) "America/Fortaleza" }

Comment: You have to use `->format(...)` method on each object. So instead of last line just use something like: `foreach($filtered as $date) { echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); }`. Here is list of possible arguments (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you can use.